# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "connect.exe": CreateProcess error=2

Tags: intellij-idea, ssh, ide, jetbrains-ide

In IntelliJ, I am trying to create and connect with a new SSH configuration

[image]

The credentials saved are all correct... when I try to launch it, I receive this error

[image]

Other configurations seems to work, and I cannot find an option in the settings to set the path of this "connect.exe". How would you solve this problem?

Comment: Please attach idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue. Also please show your ssh configuration from "Settings/Preferences | Tools | SSH Configurations"

Comment: I will do it asap

Comment: @y.bedrov done it

Comment: The only configuration that I have is in the log

Comment: Could you try to specify the absolute path to the "connect.exe" tool in the "ProxyCommand" section (https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ProxyCommand)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the configuration was automatically loading info in the *.ssh* folder under my Windows user folder. In *config* file, it was using *Proxycommand* with *connect.exe*, that IntelliJ couldn't find.